# How to force a long Request.Form to be submitted as Zero, instead of Null

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

How to force a Null form elemnt to be Zero
I have the following model class:-

```
 public partial class MemoryInfo
    {
        public long WORKSTATIONID { get; set; }
        public Nullable<long> TOTALMEMORY { get; set; }
        public Nullable<long> FREEMEMORY { get; set; }
        public Nullable<long> VIRTUALMEMORY { get; set; }
        public Nullable<long> FREEVIRTUALMEMORY { get; set; }

        public virtual SystemInfo SystemInfo { get; set; }
    }
```

And currently I am using the model class to build an API call as follow:-

```
query["ramSize"] = Request.Form["SystemInfo.MemoryInfo.TOTALMEMORY"];
query["virtualCapacity"] = Request.Form["SystemInfo.MemoryInfo.VIRTUALMEMORY"];
query["proSpeed"] = Request.Form["SPEED"];

string apiurl = System.Web.Configuration.WebConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ApiURL"];
var url = new UriBuilder(apiurl);
```

But currently if the user leave the ramSize field empty it will be sent as Null value and the API will ignore the values, while I need the following scenario; in case the ramSize field is empty to submit a values of zero .

Can anyone adive how I can do so ?
Thanks

Comment: Can't you put something like: `if ( TOTALMEMORY == null) TOTALMEMORY = 0`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Converting Null

You could use the ***?? Operator***. Which basically evaluates the preceding statement, and if it is null, uses the proceeding value.

```
query["ramSize"] = Request.Form["SystemInfo.MemoryInfo.TOTALMEMORY"] ?? 0;
```

***[MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173224.aspx)***

> The ?? operator is called the null-coalescing operator and is used to
>   define a default value for nullable value types or reference types. It
>   returns the left-hand operand if the operand is not null; otherwise it
>   returns the right operand.

Just a note, I think that `Request.Form[""]` returns a `string` so you may have to enclose `0` in quotes.

### Converting String.Empty

It seems you are in fact asking a different question, and you want to convert `String.Empty` or `""` to 0. You can use the **Tertiary Operator ?** in this case:

```
string ramSize = Request.Form["SystemInfo.MemoryInfo.TOTALMEMORY"];
query["ramSize"] = String.IsNullOrEmpty(ramSize) ? "0" : ramSize;
```

***[MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ty67wk28%28v=vs.80%29.aspx)***

> If condition is true, first expression is evaluated and becomes the
>   result; if false, the second expression is evaluated and becomes the
>   result. Only one of two expressions is ever evaluated.